# What is FME equivalent to ArcGIS Dissolve?

Tags: fme-form, merge, dissolve

I am trying to dissolve polygons that are spread out across a region. ArcMap's ModelBuilder will dissolve these polygons into a single, multi-part feature. How can I get FME to do this same thing? I have reviewed the Dissolver and FeatureMerger transformers without any luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for aggregator , give it a try .

Comment: Jorge, thanks for the suggestion. Aggregator does seem to do the trick, although it doesn't dissolve lines between polygons. It will work for what I need for now though, thanks!

Comment: @denim_dan Use the dissolver before the aggregator.  This should dissolve the lines between the boundaries and then combine the results into a single multi polygon

Comment: @MickyT thanks Micky you were right; I was able to aggregate and then dissolve just fine, thanks for the suggestion.